# PNP switch is conducting

Tags: bjt, pnp

I have a simple circuit which causes problems. This circuit should act as a switch but it is on when it should not be.

I have a VCC that can go up to 50/60 V. Q2 is a high voltage BJT so therefore I selected it. However, the circuit does not function very well. Without powering the opto-LED, when I put for example 9.5 V DC on the collector of Q2, the output at the emitter is also at 9.5 V, which tells me the BJT is on. This should not be happening.

The base is at 9.2 V and the collector of the opto coupler is also at 9.2 V which indicates the opto coupler is not on. The 9.2 V is a strange number because I suspected it to be somewhere around 8.7 V due to the diode drop.

I believe there is a small leakage current turning Q2 on.

Any idea what is wrong and how to improve this circuit?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: There needs to be a pull-up resistor from Q2 base to 50V.

Comment: The transistor in the optocoupler is probably leaking a little bit of current but still enough current to make Q2 conduct. If you add a 20 k (pull up) resistor between the base and emitter of the transistor that leakage current will no longer be able to open the transistor.

Comment: What's VCEO(max) on that opto?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Its a 4N25, according to the data sheet its 70V. You would probebly suggest using only this bjt without Q2 and use the opto coupler with 
a pull down resistor. I would get Vbe of -70 Vwould that be okay?

Comment: Vbe (reversed) should be kept to 5V or so with most transistors. Vceo (abs max) of 70V is cutting it a bit fine, but may be acceptable if your 50V supply is well regulated (not a typical vehicle supply!)

Comment: It even goes up to 62V actually so it maybe risky. the pnp bjt can go to 400 V I believe, so maybe a more robust approach to leave them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with the opto-coupler "off" there will be enough leakage current through the transistor to slightly turn on Q2.

There is a current path from the 50V, through the E-B junction of Q2 (basically a forward biassed diode), through R6 and through the opto which might be officially "off" but will still pass a bit of leakage current. That tiny bit of current passes through Q2 base and is amplified by its hfe. The current has nowhere else to go, and you probably have 0.55 or 0.6V Vbe on Q2 because of this - Q2 is "just about on".

It depends a bit on what range of voltage you expect your "50/60V" to be, but you need to ensure that the opto needs to be properly on before Vbe of Q2 gets to 0.6V or so. A resistor in the emitter of Q2 helps, but better would be a shunt resistor (about 470R should do it) from Q2 base to the 50V in.

This still allows Q2 to saturate on when the opto is on (0.47/20.47 * 50V = 1.1V, plenty to turn it on), but will shunt away the leakage current of the opto from Q2 base when it is off.

(Note however that that value likely won't alleviate the problem with 12V in, so you might have to tweak this approach to fit your expected range of input volts.)